# How to pop modal on condition of legal input

Tags: javascript, flask, modal-dialog, bootstrap-5

I am working on this journal book app with flask and bootstrap 5. Now I am working on a deletion feature, where user can input how many records they want to delete. I want this feature to pop out a confirmation modal to the user, with the corresponding row information display in the modal body. If the input is illegal(e.g., is not integer or more than the existing record counts), the flask flash will flash an error message instead.

**html of this part**

```
<form class="col-md-3" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div>
        <label for="deleteform" class="d-inline">number to delete</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="delete_number" name="delete_number" value="1" onchange="myFunction()">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#confirm_modal">delete</button>            
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="confirm_modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Delete <span id="num_to_delete"></span>records</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close"  data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p><span id="row_text"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-color"  id='delete_entry' name="delete_entry" value="cancel">delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**js**

```
<script>

var number = document.getElementById('delete_number').value;
document.getElementById("num_to_delete").innerText = number;


//create_text() is function to generate modal body text
//get_row is the object corresponding to the number we want
document.getElementById("row_text").innerText = create_text(get_row);


function myFunction() {
    number = document.getElementById('delete_number').value;
    document.getElementById("num_to_delete").innerText = number;
    get_row = obj[size - Number(number)];
    document.getElementById("row_text").innerText = create_text(get_row);
}

</script>
```

**python code** (just the idea that I want to show these flashing msgs)

```
num = request.form.get('delete_number')
if num != "":
    if num.isdigit():
        num = int(num)
        if num <= len(list_of_sheets):
            # remove last n items
            list_of_sheets = list_of_sheets[:len(list_of_sheets) - num]
            with open('file.pkl', 'wb') as
                pickle.dump(list_of_sheets, f)
            flash('succeed', category='success')
        else:
            flash('error', category='error')
    else:
        flash('error', category='error')
else:
    flash('error', category='error')
```

Now the modal will pop no matter if the input is legal or not. I know that modal is popped before submit, where my flash message is generated after submit. I am wondering there any way to have a conditional modal, if the input is legal, then the modal pop up, else just submit then flashing the error msgs.

I am not very familar with web development. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way by using javascript.

```
var del = document.getElementById('delete_button');

function myFunction() {
    number = document.getElementById('delete_number').value;
    document.getElementById("num_to_delete").innerText = number;    

    if (isNaN(number)) {
      // not a number
      // submit form to catch error
      del.removeAttribute('data-bs-toggle');
      del.removeAttribute('href');
      del.setAttribute('type', 'submit');

    } else {
      // is a number
      if (Number(number) <= size) {
        del.setAttribute('type', 'button');        
        del.setAttribute('href', '#delete_modal');
        del.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle', 'modal');            
        
        get_row = obj[size - Number(number)];
        document.getElementById("row_text").innerText = create_text(get_row);
      } else {
        // not enough rows
        // submit form to catch error
        del.removeAttribute('data-bs-toggle');
        del.removeAttribute('href');
        del.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
      }
    }
}
```

This will make btn to pop out the modal if the input is legal, and change the button's type to submit when the input is illegal.